# RegEx for java variable

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I want to capture the java variable name in java file using regex. i am able to achieve one level where variable is assigned something , but if variable is not assigned anything then how to get it ?

My Regex : `(\w*)<?>?\s*=(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*["])*$)` 
[Click here for sample](https://regex101.com/r/Plk2rB/3)
it should included both variable but not import class;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException ;
String test="test";
String test22;
String includeThisAlso ;
```

it should match the variable but not import class.

Comment: Will this work for you? `^\s*(?:List\s*<)?\w+>?\s*\K\w+(?=\s*=|\s*;)`

Comment: i replaced List in regex with any word , as it can be any class varaible .. `^\s*(?:\w*\s*<)?\w+>?\s*\K\w+(?=\s*=|\s*;)` but can you please explain the regex also , what is the \K

Comment: sure, i'll add it as an answer

Comment: In which environment or language you are going to use this regex?

Comment: @Julio also i just tried with java pattern , i think \K is not supported by java compiler.<br>  https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyy3ujp0r<br> also above regex is not matching `private final String COMMENTS =  "test";`

Comment: @revo i am using java pattern for my program.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I'm using a capturing group for the names of the variables. You'll need to reference that group for getting the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

`^\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)*?(?:\s*<\w+>)?\s+(\w+)(?=\s*[=;])`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jrIzAH/10)**

**Explained:**

```
^ \s*              # Line starts with one or more spaces
  \w+              # a word (1 or more letters, numbers and '_')
  (?:\s+\w+)*?     # several extra words, separated by spaces. Ungreedy
  (?:\s*<\w+>)?    # Optional '<' + Word '>'
  \s+(\w+)         # Capture the variable with a group ()
  (?=\s*[=;])      # It must be followed by spaces and then '=' or ';'
```

Later on, you just need to reference the first capturing group. that will have the name of the variable

**Editted** to allow matching generics.

Comment: its not matching variable: `private final String COMMENTS =  "test";`

Comment: Glad to hear. You may mark the answer as 'Accepted' if it worked for you.

Comment: @Julio thanks for the answer. Your explanation doesn't match the updated pattern, can you please update it? particularly around `(?:<\w+>)?`

Comment: @Kartik Done! Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Julio, upvoted. If you can modify it to make it work for generics, that would be awesome! `private List<String> test;`

Comment: Thanks! I think now it should for that case too. Just let me know.

Comment: Fixed! I forgot We could'nt use PCRE regexes